# How to fix invalid/stripped json?

Tags: mysql, json

I have a problem with JSON. Before we discovered error, column 'data' in mysql database had a type VARCHAR(255), where serialized json stored. About 2 months it worked well, but when project started to grow, 255 chars - became insufficient. But we forget to change type to TEXT. Now we have a problem, that our serialized json is stripped to 255 chars and now is invalid. I dont care about lost data, but I need to make minimal parsable/valid json.

for ex:

`data =  '{"state_id":[null,20],"dispatcher_id":[null,6057525],"uir":[null,{"level":"2"'`

I need to make it valid, like this

`data =  '{"state_id":[null,20],"dispatcher_id":[null,6057525],"uir":[null,{"level":"2"}]}'`

add `}]}` at the end of json.

Is there any quick way to do it? Or I should write my own parser/fixer?

Comment: You should write your parser/fixer.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why don't you care about lost data? :)

Comment: if all miss just `}]}` use concat to add it, or use a where to add it to the correct row, if there is alot of diferent cases, write a parser/fixer

Comment: if you don't care about losing data, just replace all rows with `{}`

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius - What'd be the point of caring at this point? :)

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius Presumably he doesn't have much of a choice. It's gone, forever.

Comment: I dont care about data, because all CRITICAL DATA are in first 255 chars, other data are metadata, so I dont care. Every JSON stipped in different parts. I can have json ending like this '{..., "data":', or just like this '{..., "data":["key' etc. There are a lot of variations.

Comment: At this point, I need to write "missing endings" to make json valid. I should scan a string, and say: Hey, here `}` is missing, and here is missing a value for key, ohh.. Here is missing `"` for key definition...etc..

Comment: Off topic, but note: since you're referring to this data as JSON, I should point out that technically it isn't -- the `data = ` bit at the start of the string is not valid JSON. A valid JSON string should not have that bit. What you actually have there is a chunk of Javascript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this task, so I want to share [my solution](https://github.com/cidevant/Fix-cutted-invalid-incomplete-json)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jsonlist](https://github.com/zaach/jsonlint)

it's a pure implementation in JavaScript for validating JSON.

According to the validation you'll know what is missing in the end and add the missing value.
you can also check a [demo online](http://jsonlint.com/)